# Как сохранить изображение на сервер и вернуть в переменную ссылку на файл?

Tags: javascript, php

```
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("qq").onclick = function() {
    html2canvas(field).then(function(canvas) {
        var my_screen = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.5)
        console.log(my_screen)
      document.getElementById("vk").addEventListener('click', function(){
        window.open('https://vkontakte.ru/share.php?url='+my_screen+',sharer,status=0,toolbar=0,width=650,height=500')
    })
    });
};
```

}

Подскажите как на fetch отправить из переменной my_screen код base64 с помощью php сохранить ее и вернуть ссылку на данный файл. Как это сделать на ajax+php знаю, а вот ванильный javascript для меня тяжеловат.

Comment: А не тяжеловат ли URL-адрес получается? Почему ajax+php исключает ванильность? И почему не использовать [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) и метод POST?

Comment: Ну конечно тяжеловат, поэтому и хочу полученный base64, декодировать и сохранить с помощью php в папку на сервер и уже вернуть нормальный урл картинки. Просто вопрос как использовать fetch, а ajax + php  добавляет библиотеку jquery

Comment: "ajax + php добавляет библиотеку jquery" - это не обязательно. Можно нативно работать с XMLHttpRequest. А использование Fetch API не сильно отличается от jquery. [Тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0) и примеры есть.